# Google Docs - Reference a sheet from cell value

Tags: reference, google-sheets, google-docs, intervals

I have a column of "sheet names" and I need to use it to reference the sheets in a formula where I use an interval from these sheets.
How can I do it ?

- I found something about indirect() but it seems restricted for single cell reference only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indirect is not only for single cell reference.

You need it to be typed out like this (if we say you want A1:B10 in Sheet2 when you are in Sheet1):

Sheet2!A1:B10 (in A1), dont use '' around the reference.

=indirect(A1) would then type out the entire range A1:B10 from Sheet2.